# Making a descriptor for the poll function

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe

I find the poll() function quite useful for multiplexing pipes and sockets, but I wanted to extend on that and poll my own mediums, as in implement my own pipe and have it work with poll for POLLIN and POLLOUT events, How would I do that?

```
int self = GenerateMyPipe();
int sock = socket(...);
struct pollfd fd[2];
//Init Pollfd and Stuff...
poll(fd, 2, -1); 
...
```

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Are you using Linux? See [eventfd()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard POSIX method for this, but on Linux you can use [`eventfd()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)

> `eventfd()` creates an "eventfd object" that can be used as an event
>          wait/notify mechanism by user-space applications, and by the kernel
>          to notify user-space applications of events.  The object contains an
>          unsigned 64-bit integer (uint64_t) counter that is maintained by the
>          kernel.  This counter is initialized with the value specified in the
>          argument initval.
>   ...
>   The returned file descriptor supports `poll(2)` (and analogously
>                 `epoll(7)`) and `select(2)`, as follows:
>
> - The file descriptor is readable (the `select(2)` `readfds`
>      argument; the `poll(2)` `POLLIN` flag) if the counter has a
>      value greater than 0.
> - The file descriptor is writable (the `select(2)` `writefds`
>      argument; the `poll(2)` `POLLOUT` flag) if it is possible to
>      write a value of at least "1" without blocking.

You change the counter by writing to the descriptor.